# How do I use Tools in 5th ed D&D

Tags: dnd-5e

Are there any hard and fast examples or rules for 5th ed D&D that govern how you use tool sets? I know they have some minor info about Thieves tools and Herbalism kits... but I am specifically looking for the Artisan's tool sets.

I have looked in the PHB and the DMG about how to use things like the Alchemists and Tinker tools and havent found anything. The section about tools uses carptenter/woodworking tools and said things like Dex check to make a wood flute, Int to make a wood secret door, and Str to make a ballista/war machine. That seems to indicate, if you can think of something to build, and the tools apply you can build it. But how do i know what the DC should be, how much it would cost and how long it takes to complete a project?

Comment: Related but not quite duplicate, I think: [What is the purpose of having proficiency with artisan's tools?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76900/what-is-the-purpose-of-having-proficiency-with-artisans-tools)

Comment: Similarly to @PurpleMonkey 's link, [Guide for using all the tools and kits](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80313/guide-for-using-all-the-tools-and-kits).

Answer (score 17):

### It works as any other ability check

When a character tries to craft something using tools, he/she must have the respective proficiency in order to succeed:

> You must be proficient with tools related to the object you are trying to create (PHB p.187)

This is related not only to crafting:

> trying to open a lock requires proficiency with thieves’ tools (PHB, p.175)

DM asks the player to make an ability check. All the attributes - ability modifier, time, DC, possible negative results - are set by the DM.

Possible use cases depend on the tool. For Artisan's tools they might be:

- crafting an item
- repairing an item
- modifying an item (i.e. tweak armor size, if you use "Variant: Equipment sizes" rule)
- helping with craft
- appraising other's work

As a DM, normally you choose DC according to the following list:

> **Trivial (DC 0)** A task that is so easy that isn't worth a check. An adventurer can almost always succeed automatically.
>   **Very Easy (DC 5)** Requires a minimum level of competence or a bit of luck to accomplish.
>   **Easy (DC 10)** Requires a minimum level of competence or a bit of luck to accomplish.
>   **Moderate (DC 15)** Requires a bit more competence to accomplish. Can be completed more often than not by a character with both natural aptitude and specialized training.
>   **Hard (DC 20)** Include anything beyond the capabilities of the average person without aid or exceptional talent. Even with a bit of training and skill you still need some luck to pull it off (or maybe some specialized training).
>   **Very Hard (DC 25)** Achievable only by especially talented individuals. Nobody else should even bother trying.
>   **Formidable (DC 30)** Achievable only by the most trained, experienced, and talented individuals, and they probably still need help to pull it off.

### Speaking of crafting time, normally it takes days

From the PHB, p. 187:

> For every day of downtime you spend crafting, you
>   can craft one or more items with a total market value
>   not exceeding 5 gp, and you must expend raw materials
>   worth half the total market value. If something you
>   want to craft has a market value greater than 5 gp, you
>   make progress every day in 5-gp increments until you
>   reach the market value of the item. For example, a suit
>   of plate arm or (market value 1,500 gp) takes 300 days
>   to craft by yourself.

Comment: Just curious, but where does it say in the material that you can't use tools at all with no proficiency?

Comment: @Eidolon108 PhB, p.152 - "Without the key, a creature proficient with thieves’ tools can pick this lock"; p.175 - "trying to open a lock requires proficiency with thieves’ tools"; p.187 - "You must be proficient
with tools related to the object you are trying to create
(typically artisan’s tools)"

Comment: You might want to clarify that it works "like" an ability check because it *is* an ability check.